# Notice: Undefined index: PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I am having a little bit of issues with some Undefined index. I realize this could be solved by changing it the error reporting using `error_reporting(E_ALL);`, or `ini_set('display_errors', '1');`, but would like to solve this without the need to change that. Right here is my block of code that throws the error.

```
// print out errors
              if (!empty($errors)){
                echo '<div class="form_errors">';
                foreach ($errors as $key => $value) {
                  var_dump($value);
                  if (isset($value) ==  null or empty($value)){
                    $value = ' A blank value ';
                  }
                  echo '<p>Please check '. $key . ' for errors.' . $value . 'is not a valid entry.</p>';
                }
                echo '</div>';
              }
```

The part that processes my form on submit is

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    //create the fields you would want required and what fields on form to check.
    $fields = array(
      'required' => array(
            'name' => '^[a-zA-Z\`\-\s]{1,30}$', //only letters plus apostrophe and hyphens, and up to 30 characters
            'Address1' => '^[a-zA-Z0-9\s\.]{1,50}$' // only letters plus numbers, spaces, periods, and up to 30 characters
        ),
      'fields' => array( 
            'name' => $_POST['name'],
            'Address1' => $_POST['Address1'],
            'Address2' => $_POST['address2']
        ),
      'redirect' => 'thankyou.php'
    );
    $errors = TForm::validate($fields);
    // if no errors redirect
    if (empty($errors)){
      TForm::redirect($fields);
    }
  }
```

And my TForm class looks like this

```
class TForm {
    //validation returns an error array when done. 
    public function validate($fields){
        $errors = array();
        foreach($fields['fields'] as $key=>$value) {
            foreach ($fields['required'] as $req_key => $req_value) {
                if ($key == $req_key){
                    $req_key = '\''.$req_value.'\'';
                    if (preg_match($req_key , $value) == false) {
                        $errors[$key] = $value;
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
        return $errors;
    }

    //redirect function
    public function redirect($fields){
        header('Location: '. $fields['redirect']);
    }

}
```

This is also the first class I have ever wrote so if anyone feels up to pointing out where I could have performed better or broke standards. 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~update~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

@jordan Sorry I wasn't clear about the error reporting `E_ALL` is what I'm currently using and on a production machine this error wouldn't be reported because you would be using `0`. My solution was to use `!empty($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name']:''` If I am thinking correctly if it isn't empty it uses whatever is in `$_POST['Name']` and if it is empty it sets the value to `''`.

```
'fields' => array( 
            'Name' => !empty($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name']:'',
            'Address1' => !empty($_POST['Address1']) ? $_POST['Address1']:'',
            'Address2' => !empty($_POST['Address2']) ? $_POST['Address2']:''
        )
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~update2~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

@mike using isset results in the field always failing ie

```
'fields' => array( 
            'Name' => !isset($_POST['Name']) ? $_POST['Name']:'',
            'Address1' => !isset($_POST['Address1']) ? $_POST['Address1']:'',
            'Address2' => !isset($_POST['Address2']) ? $_POST['Address2']:''
        )
```

results in when name equals a valid variable, such as Frank Wiebenga

```
Please check Name for errors. A blank value is not a valid entry.
Please check Address1 for errors. A blank value is not a valid entry.
```

using the empty method when Name equals a valid variable, such as Frank Wiebenga returns correctly

```
Please check Address1 for errors. A blank value is not a valid entry.
```

Comment: what is full error message, which index undefined ?

Comment: error_reporting Development Value: "E_ALL | E_STRICT" ALWAYS in which line is the error?

Comment: Also note that regardless your error, this line does not make sense: `if (isset($value) ==  null or empty($value))`. `isset` returns boolean, so it can never be literally null, though checking it with == null will also evaluate to false... but instead of this whole construct you could've just checked `if(empty($value))`

Comment: You should *always* use an `E_ALL` error-reporting level in your development environment. Without it you're just making your job as a developer more difficult. By all means use a lower error-reporting level in your production environment, but not in development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your update, you should use `isset` instead of `empty`, so you avoid the undefined index error:

```
$name = (isset($_POST['Name'])) ? $_POST['Name'] : '';
```

More info on [isset](https://www.php.net/isset).

-- Update --

Try flipping the ternary assignment:

```
$name = (!isset($_POST['Name'])) ? '' : $_POST['Name'];
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the Full error message to help you better but form your script i notice that the only external variable not declared are the `$_POST` values please update your code below and lets know the exact errors you still have .

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
    //create the fields you would want required and what fields on form to check.

    if(!isset($_POST['name']) || !isset($_POST['Address1']) || !isset($_POST['address2']))
    {
        die("Empty POST NOt allowed ");
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

General answer to the `undefined index` notice:

`$myArray['myKey']` will produce an undefined index notice if `myKey` doesn't exist in the `$myArray` array. You can solve this by checking for its existing prior to using it.

```
if (array_key_exists($myArray, 'myKey')) {
  echo $myArray['myKey'];
}
```